# Can a real valued function have a limit be imaginary valued?

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

so from my knowledge there are some functions that have a limit be imaginary valued. For example $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}(\sqrt{-x}) = i$$ but this function does not even exist around the point $x = 1$ (at least for real values). So my question is that does there exist a function $f(x)$ that is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ except for one point $x = a$ where the following limit is an imaginary number: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}(f(x))$$ And also does such a function perhaps exist in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the same conditions? Note that I know that there can be different "directional" limits for a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so can there be a limit which is the same imaginary number on all "directions"?

Comment: formally if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ then any limit of $f$, by definition, must be real. If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ but is real-valued, then this still must have real limits since $\Bbb R$ is closed in $\Bbb C$

Comment: Not according to the definition of limit

Comment: I think you run into issues because the function is multi-valued and there is probably some branch cut here which makes this limit not exist. I imagine it will bounce between $\{-i,i\}$ depending on the number of rotations you take in the complex plane.

Comment: Yes, if the limit is 0. 0 is a pure imaginary number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. We can assume without loss of generality that the point is $c=0$. By the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of a limit, if $L$ is the limit, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, $0<\lvert x\rvert<\delta$, $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert<\epsilon$. But if $L = a + bi$ with $b\ne0$, $\lvert y - L\rvert \ge \lvert b\rvert$ for all real numbers $y$, including all values of $f$.